# Python mock a base class's attribute

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, patch

For testing, I'd like to change a single Class instance's attribute (self.attr) in a base class.

```
# app.py
class Base():
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr = 'original_value'

    def show(self):
        print(self.attr) 

class App():
    def __init__(self):  
        self.base = Base()
```

Here is my attempt at mocking the Base class instance's attribute `attr`

```
# test_app.py
from mock import Mock
from app import App

def test_mock_inherited_class_instance():
    """ With mocking. Change app.base.attr from 'original_value' to 'new_value'.
    """
    app = App()
    app.base = Mock()
    app.base.attr = 'new_value'
    app.base.show() # I'd like this to show 'new_value', NOT 'original_value'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instance member or instance variable of a class is different from class attribute or class property. this mocked the `attr` only by keeping all class attributes.

```
import mock
from app import App
from app import Base
import unittest
from StringIO import StringIO
class TestApp(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('sys.stdout', new_callable=StringIO)
    def test_mock_instance_var(self, mocked_stdout):

        base = Base()
        app = App()

        mock_base = mock.MagicMock(name='Base', spec=Base)
        instance = mock_base.return_value
        instance.attr.return_value = 'mmm'
        base.attr = instance.attr.return_value
        self.assertEqual(base.attr, 'mmm')

        app.base = base

        self.assertEqual(app.base.attr, 'mmm')
        # the print stdout of show()
        app.base.show()
        self.assertEqual(mocked_stdout.getvalue(), 'mmm\n')
```

Comment: I tested this out and it works well. Thank you so much!